# How to make an infinite scroll with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm doing a blog post and to store my posts I put them in a JSON file and I display them on my website. The problem that I see comming is that when it will have too many post the loading will be to long, so I know that I need to do an infinite scroll, but I'm not sure how to do it.

exemple of post store in the JSON file

```
{
      "video": "RyPVV03hUNE",
      "title": "Titre",
      "star":"1",
      "categories":"Categories" 
    }
```

So what ressources can I read to help me in my project.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You're expected to do some research and attempt this yourself.  Stack Overflow is not a place to request code to be written for you.  When you have specific issues with existing code then we can help.

Comment: I think AJAX is normally used for this. When the page first appears you might have (for example) 20 posts. As the user scrolls down more posts appear below the 20 but without having to refresh the page. That way the user does not have to wait for all the posts to arrive before being able to see the first ones.

Comment: You can take this example: [Infinite Scroll (pure JS)](https://codepen.io/wernight/pen/YyvNoW) and replace `loadMore` function by an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) function to load your json by splitting your data by part (_n_ number of posts) like pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the perfect example for what I wanted to do.
This exemple load the results of a JSON(or array) per group of 10 when we reach the bottom of the page. So for anyone else, if you want to do that I recommend you to check this example:https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179463/infinite-scroll-for-currency-list.